# cast value as negative float if there is a "-" sign at the end with pandas

Tags: python, pandas

Within a dataframe I have a column called 'Val' where I have float values, but the negative values are represented by the '-' sign AT THE END! And therefore it is interpreted as object
i.e

```
>>> df['Val'].drop_duplicates().sort_values()
5          0.00000
1873      0.20000-
496      100.00000
425      2.00000
Name: Val, Length: 4, dtype: object
```

How can I convert the negative values into true negative values and then convert the column to float.

If it would a list I would do something like this:

```
if row[i][-1:] == '-':
    row[i] = float(row[i][:-1]) * -1
else:
    row[i] = float(row[i])
```

What is the pandas way to do this?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use `loc` to correct only entries ending with `-`

```
mask = df.Val.str.endswith('-')
df.loc[mask, 'Val'] = '-' + df.loc[mask, 'Val'].str[:-1]
```

and then convert to numeric `dtype`

```
df['Val'] = pd.to_numeric(df.Val, errors='coerce')
```

Final result

```
5         0.0
1873     -0.2
496     100.0
425       2.0
Name: Val, dtype: float64
```

Answer (score 2):

You can do with `str.strip`, then using `np.where` with `str.endswith`

```
s1=df.x.str.strip('+|-').astype('float')
np.where(df.x.str.endswith('-'),s1*-1,s1)
array([  0. ,  -0.2, 100. ,   2. ])
```