# Converting Negative Number in String Format to Numeric when Sign as at the end

Tags: pandas, dataframe, format, negative-number

I have certain numbers within a column of my dataframe that have negative numbers in a string format like this: "500.00-" I need to convert every negative number within the column to numeric format. I'm sure there's an easy way to do this, but I have struggled finding one specific to pandas dataframe. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

I have tried the basic to_numeric function as shown below, but it doesn't read it in correctly. Also, only some of the numbers within the column are negative, therefore I can't simply remove all the negative signs and multiply the column by 1.

```
Q1['Credit'] = pd.to_numeric(Q1['Credit'])
```

Comment: Did you, perhaps, read that data from an excel spreadsheet?

Comment: `df.num.str.extract('(\d+.\d+)',expand=False).astype(float)` ??

Comment: Does this answer your question? [cast value as negative float if there is a "-" sign at the end with pandas](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55551982/cast-value-as-negative-float-if-there-is-a-sign-at-the-end-with-pandas)

Answer (score 1):

Sample data:

```
df:
      num
0   50.00
1  60.00-
2  70.00+
3  -80.00
```

---

Using series `str` accessor to check last digit. If it is `'-'` or `'+'`, swap it to front. Use `df.mask` to apply it only to rows having -/+ as suffix. Finally, `astype` column to `float`

```
df.num.mask(df.num.str[-1].isin(['-','+']), df.num.str[-1].str.cat(df.num.str[:-1])).astype('float')

Out[1941]:
0    50.0
1   -60.0
2    70.0
3   -80.0
Name: num, dtype: float64
```

Answer (score 1):

Possibly a bit explicit but would work

```
# build a mask of negative numbers
m_neg = Q1["Credit"].str.endswith("-")
# remove - signs
Q1["Credit"] = Q1["Credit"].str.rstrip("-")
# convert to number
Q1["Credit"] = pd.to_numeric(Q1["Credit"])
# Apply the mask to create the negatives
Q1.loc[m_neg, "Credit"] *= -1
```

Comment: Of course, can be done in one line like https://stackoverflow.com/a/56333633/2314391

Answer (score 0):

Let us consider the following example dataframe:

```
Q1 = pd.DataFrame({'Credit':['500.00-', '100.00', '300.00-']})

    Credit
0  500.00-
1   100.00
2  300.00-
```

We can use `str.endswith` to create a mask which indicates the negative numbers. Then we use `np.where` to conditionally convert the numbers to negative:

```
m1 = Q1['Credit'].str.endswith('-')
m2 = Q1['Credit'].str[:-1].astype(float)
Q1['Credit'] = np.where(m1, -m2, m2)
```

**Output**

```
   Credit
0  -500.0
1   100.0
2  -300.0
```

Comment: This is not working always, since 50.01 will be returned as 50.0. In this case, the proper solution will be 

``m1 = Q1['Credit'].str.endswith('-')

m2 = Q1['Credit'].str[:-1].astype(float)

Q1['Credit'] = np.where(m1, -m2, Q1['Credit'].astype(float))``